# Can we synonymize the `apache-openoffice` and `openoffice.org` tags please?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Since the tags [apache-openoffice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/apache-openoffice) and [openoffice.org](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/openoffice.org) tags are for the same topic, can we please synonymize them?

Answer (score 2):

Done, retagged 11 questions 3 of them has nothing to do with OO.o ([one of them was about apache D:](https://askubuntu.com/posts/384970/revisions))

Comment: I was hoping to synonymize them, but whatever.

Comment: meh, is always good to review it before hand...